# How can I show how many units have been sold of a single item?

Tags: shopify

On the product page of the item, how?

I know you can show how many are in stock, but how do I show how many have been sold?

Answer (score 1):

One way. Record all your orders in an App. Parse the orders for products and update a counter in your App. When rendering the Product, use a callback to the App to get the current count sold. Another way, attach a metafield resource to each Product with a count. The App could then update this count per sale, and you simply render the current count using Liquid.

Comment: wow this sounds like I need a lot of development skills:( Thank you for your help, I just wish there was a way in Shopify where I could automatically show this with some liquid tweaking like showing how many are still in stock.